# Sum within a window that is defined in column

Tags: r, performance, sum, data.table, window-functions

I want to implement the `sum(x)` of N next rows for each `data.table` row within a group, where N is value from `window` column.

Code to generate sample data:

```
set.seed(100)
ids <- 1:100
x <- floor(runif(100, 1, 100))
groups <- floor(runif(100, 1, 10)) * 10
window <- floor(runif(100, 1, 5))

library('data.table')
data <- data.table(ids, x, groups, window)
setkey(data, groups, ids)
```

Top rows:

```
 ids  x groups window
 1:   3 55     10      4
 2:   9 55     10      1
 3:  13 28     10      1
 4:  16 67     10      3
 5:  26 17     10      3
 6:  30 28     10      2
 7:  36 89     10      2
 8:  38 63     10      3
 9:  42 86     10      3
10:  48 88     10      1
11:  49 21     10      1
12:  59 60     10      3
13:  65 45     10      4
14:  67 46     10      2
15:  88 25     10      4
16:  19 36     20      2
```

So for the first row the resulting value will be calculated based on the sum of current and next 4 rows: res = 55 + 55 + 28 + 67 + 17 = 222

For the row 15 where the group ends I just need the value of the current row: res = 25 + 0 (no rows) = 25.

This is a pseudo code for this logic:

```
res <- data[, .(ids, groups, x, window , 
            result = sum(.SD[.CurrentRow:(.CurrentRow + Window)], na.rm = T)), 
            by = groups, .SDcols = c("x")]
```

I hope this can be implemented via `data.table`. I want to avoid `for` loop implementation for this.

Comment: Maybe you should use `set.seed` before generating a sample?

Comment: Yes, just updated the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible to do this without iterating over all rows, so here's one such solution:

```
data[, end := pmin(.I + window, .I[.N]), by = groups][
     , res := sum(data$x[.I:end]), by = 1:nrow(data)][1:16]
#    ids  x groups window end res
# 1:   3 55     10      4   5 222
# 2:   9 55     10      1   3  83
# 3:  13 28     10      1   4  95
# 4:  16 67     10      3   7 201
# 5:  26 17     10      3   8 197
# 6:  30 28     10      2   8 180
# 7:  36 89     10      2   9 238
# 8:  38 63     10      3  11 258
# 9:  42 86     10      3  12 255
#10:  48 88     10      1  11 109
#11:  49 21     10      1  12  81
#12:  59 60     10      3  15 176
#13:  65 45     10      4  15 116
#14:  67 46     10      2  15  71
#15:  88 25     10      4  15  25
#16:  19 36     20      2  18 173
```

---

As alexis_laz points out, you can do better by computing the `cumsum` once and then subtracting the extra part out, thus avoiding explicitly iterating over rows:

```
data[, res := { cs <- cumsum(x); 
                cs[pmin(1:.N + window, .N)] - shift(cs, fill = 0)}
     , by = groups]
```

I will try to explain what happens here:

- `res := {...}` adds a column to our data.table with R calculation inside the brackets;
- `cs = cumsum(x)` calculates running sum for all rows within the group;
- `cs[pmin(1:.N + window, .N)]` takes value of running sum at the end of the window or at last row of the group;
- `shift(cs, fill = 0)` gets the running sum from the preceding row;
- difference of the two gives the sum of items within the window.

As there are several working answers to this question, I think it is worth providing benchmarking here:

```
library(microbenchmark)
m <- microbenchmark(
               "tapply(rawr)" = tapplyWay(dd),
               "data.table(eddi)" = data[, end := pmin(.I + window, .I[.N]), by = groups][
                   , res := sum(data$x[.I:end]), by = 1:nrow(data)],
               "data.table(alexis_laz)" = data[, res := {cs = cumsum(x); cs[pmin(1:.N + window, .N)] - shift(cs, fill = 0)}
                                               , by = groups],
               times = 10)
print(m)
boxplot(m)
```

Result for 10^5 rows sample:

```
Unit: milliseconds
            expr     min     lq      mean    median      uq    max        neval
       tapply(rawr) 2575.12 2761.365 2898.63 2905.77  3041.08  3127.86    10
   data.table(eddi) 1418.92 1570.230 1758.70 1656.14  1977.59  2358.85    10
     dt(alexis_laz) 6.82    7.73     8.78    8.09     10.37    12.37119    10
```

[image: benchmarking of solutions]

Comment: This is what i was looking for! and it is 3 times faster on the 1m rows data set.

Comment: Following this logic, the "end" and, additionally, a `cumsum(x)` column could be built by "groups" and, then, index the "cumsum" appropriately. I.e. (and unless I'm missing something) `data[, { cs = cumsum(x); cs[pmin(window + seq_along(window), length(window))] - c(0, cs[seq_len(length(window) - 1)]) }, by = groups]`

Comment: @Bulat check out the edit based on alexis_laz's idea - should be significantly faster

Comment: can you elaborate on how the expressions in `{..}` work

Comment: It is 200 time faster.. On the real dataset it will possibly be even more.

Comment: The curly brackets simply create a scope in which you can evaluate multiple expressions, same as elsewhere in R.

Comment: so the `;` goes for a new line there?

Comment: @alexis_laz can you please post your comment as an answer

Comment: @eddi, I have updated your answer as I think it is quite a useful solution. hope that is ok

Comment: thanks - absolutely - that's what the edit button is for :)

Answer (score 1):

First we load the `base` package and convert our `data.table` to a `data.frame`

```
set.seed(100)
ids <- 1:100
x <- floor(runif(100, 1, 100))
groups <- floor(runif(100, 1, 10)) * 10
window <- floor(runif(100, 1, 5))

library('data.table')
data <- data.table(ids, x, groups, window)
setkey(data, groups, ids)

dd <- as.data.frame(data)
```

And basically bind the rows into a larger data frame which we can use to summarize using your favorite aggregation method

```
tmp <- tapply(seq(nrow(dd)), dd$groups, function(ii) {
  idx <- Map(`:`, ii, ii + dd$window[ii])
  out <- dd[unlist(idx), ]
  out$idx <- rep(dd$ids[ii], lengths(idx))
  out[out$groups %in% dd$groups[ii], ]
})
tmp <- do.call('rbind', tmp)

res <- aggregate(x ~ idx + groups, tmp, sum)

#    idx groups   x
# 1    3     10 222
# 2    9     10  83
# 3   13     10  95
# 4   16     10 201
# 5   26     10 197
# 6   30     10 180
# 7   36     10 238
# 8   38     10 258
# 9   42     10 255
# 10  48     10 109
# 11  49     10  81
# 12  59     10 176
# 13  65     10 116
# 14  67     10  71
# 15  88     10  25
# 16  19     20 173

identical(table(dd$groups), table(res$group))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Got 3 vs 80 (`for` loop) sec on 10^5 sample. This is going to save me a lot of time, thanks a lot!